# Cashier Commission Report AX 2012

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2012

I am assigned to develop a SSRS report which will show cashier commission for a given time period, the report will include columns such as employee name, item ID, sales amount, discount and COMMISSION.

This is AX 2012, we have commission groups defined and assigned on items, and further sales rep groups are also defined, can you guys shine some light on how I can fetch commission information from database, I am willing to write a stored proc in sql which I will call in my report for this. I could not find any column in retailTransactionTable or RetailTransactionSalesTrans table about commission.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the CommissionTrans table.